# Angular busy error Template specified could not be loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use Angular busy in my application.My code is very simple which I have taken from the github Angular busy sample

```
<div cg-busy="promise"></div>
$scope.promise = $http.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/3');
```

But I'm getting the error

"Template specified for cgBusy (angular-busy.html) could not be loaded."

Comment: can you include some more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is trying to use the default templateUrl that is shipped with cgBusy. Did you try overriding the templateUrl per the documentation on the github page?

```
angular.module('your_app').value('cgBusyDefaults',{
  message:'Loading Stuff',
  backdrop: false,
  templateUrl: 'my_custom_template.html',
  delay: 300,
  minDuration: 700,
  wrapperClass: 'my-class my-class2'
});
```

**Edit:** 
As far as the location of the template... I looked at the source of the plugin and it using the [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache). See that documentation for how to add a template to it.

Comment: Where should I put the custom template.I'm using ASP mvc.I have already tried to give it the path of the templateurl but it gave me 404.

Comment: I edited my post. The template is actually loaded through the $templateCache.

Comment: Thanks  sourdoughdetzel . I created a custom template named angular-busy.html  and placed it in the view  where cgBusy was looking for it and loader showed up on page refresh.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.

**i crate an html page with our custome loader.**

updateed **my_custom_template.html** to newly created html name.

templateUrl: 'my_custom_template.html',

it worked.